# Pyspark - set random seed for reproducible values

Tags: random, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that I want to add random values to in a repeated fashion to guarantee the same output.  I've tried setting numpy.random.seed and random.seed, but each execution of the below code continues to generate different sequences of random values.

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+
 | 7 | 15| 19| 21| 27|
 +---------------+---+
 | 0 |  1|  0|  0|  0|
 | 0 |  0|  0|  1|  0|
 | 0 |  0|  0|  1|  0|
 | 2 |  0|  0|  0|  0|
 | 4 |  0|  3|  0|  0|
 | 5 |  0| 25|  0|  0| 
 | 6 |  2|  0|  0|  0|
```

Here's my current implementation:

```
import random
import numpy as np

#set seed
random.seed(1234)
np.random.seed(1234)

#create dataframe
df = sc.parallelize([
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 25,0, 0, 0],
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]).toDF(('7', '15', '19', '21', '27'))

 random_df = data.select("*").rdd.map(
        lambda x, r=random: [Row(float(r.random() + row)) for row in x]).toDF(data.columns)
```

In my latest attempt at a solution above, I pass the reference to random into my lambda expression, but I still get different values with each execution despite setting the seed.  Any thoughts or ideas on how to solve this challenge?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rand
random_df = df.select(*((col(c) + rand(seed=1234)).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
```

Comment: how to ensure reproducible values across spark sessions? wondering if you can help, i asked this separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59077897/5262014?sem=2

Comment: @AshishKumar Reproducible values should always be same. You might be having it in different order so I would suggest to sort column(s) and then verify if you still observe any differences. Thanks!

Comment: @Prem you're right! precisely what i am observing - the random values are not getting assigned to same rows (each row in df has an id). So my question was is it possible to ensure same random value gets assigned to an id for reproducibility? This is what my linked SO post asks about as well, would appreciate any help/guidance :)